# Why libclcore in directory "host" in android 4.4 source code not update like target?

Tags: android, llvm, android-4.4-kitkat, renderscript

Now I want to add a function into RenderScript to support a new interface by myself.

I wrote the code and add myFunc.c file into "android-4.4-src/frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/", and modify Android.mk(append myFunc.c to clcore_base_files at line 20):

```
clcore_base_files := \
    rs_allocation.c \
    rs_cl.c \
    rs_core.c \
    rs_element.c \
    rs_mesh.c \
    rs_matrix.c \
    rs_program.c \
    rs_sample.c \
    rs_sampler.c \
    convert.ll \
    allocation.ll \
    rsClamp.ll \
    myFunc.c
```

Then add myFunc.rsh into "android-4.4-src/frameworks/rs/scriptc/", and include myFunc.rsh in rs_core.rsh which in the same directory:

```
#include "myFunc.rsh"
```

And then I rebuild:

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk-eng
$ make sdk
```

The weird thing is: libclcore.bc in "**out/target/product/generic/system/lib/**" is the new version which contains the function I wrote, but the libclcore.bc in "**out/host.linux-x86/sdk/androidXXX/build-tools/android-4.4.3.2xxx/renderscript/lib**" is the old version.

I want to update the old version in "host" like the one in "target" when rebuild.

Is there some configurations I forgot?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what this "host"-side build of libclcore.bc is. That path looks suspicious (even with fixing the "host." part). I think you are looking at the libclcore.bc that a prior SDK release installed in your out/ directory.

Comment: Yes. But I don't know why there are two different libclcore.bc in out/host/ and out/target/. Now the SDK works well, so I am sure libclcore.bc in out/target/ is the one being used. So, is another nesessary?

Comment: No. Whatever is in your out/host directory was not put there by AOSP (and is not needed for any AOSP-like builds).